# How to use sql command mid or substring correct?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to use this ...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,1,1) AS name
FROM names group by SUBSTRING(name,1,1);
```

it works nearly perfect ... but ... in my language (slovak) we have different letters .. so this put forexample letter 'ž' and 'z' together .. but it is different ... can you help me with this?

output from names

```
Filip
Ferdinand
Žofia
Zdeno
Zara
```

should be

```
F
Ž
Z
```

but it is only

```
F
Z
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=RDBMS&oq=RDBMS&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: RDBMS = the database engine: MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle, MS Access, PostgreSQL, SQLite. Their implementations all differ so it's important information for us to know.

Comment: The table or column's _collation_ is what governs the aspect causing your troubles.

Comment: I got it :-) It works ... I added this before select ... mysql_query("ALTER TABLE names MODIFY name varchar(500) COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs;");

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `binary` operator:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(binary name, 1, 1) AS name
FROM names
group by SUBSTRING(binary name, 1, 1);
```